# Meteor: Couldn't deploy

Tags: deployment, meteor

I deployed a site successfully a few days ago and was able to configure logins and do other stuff but today it is down. The strange thing is I deploy to a different location without any changes and now I couldn't even access the page to configure stuff.  I don't really know how to debug these things. Here is the logs

```
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING timers.js:103
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING                                                              ^
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Could not locate any valid servers in initial seed list
    at MongoClient.connect.connectFunction (/meteor/containers/6c32717b-367c-bd8f-b229-ad69088fe830/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo-livedata/main/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:281:52)
    at Db.open (/meteor/containers/6c32717b-367c-bd8f-b229-ad69088fe830/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo-livedata/main/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:267:16)
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/meteor/containers/6c32717b-367c-bd8f-b229-ad69088fe830/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo-livedata/main/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:499:7)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at connection.on._self._poolState (/meteor/containers/6c32717b-367c-bd8f-b229-ad69088fe830/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo-livedata/main/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:168:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
    at Socket.timeoutHandler (/meteor/containers/6c32717b-367c-bd8f-b229-ad69088fe830/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo-livedata/main/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:463:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:188:8)
    at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 1
[Wed Sep 11 2013 15:19:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the timing, looks like the very brief outage from this morning. Could you check it again and let me know if everything is back to normal?