# Meteor crashes after deploy

Tags: mongodb, deployment, meteor

I have made a prototype app on my own server, an works great.
But when deploying it to meteor.com, I can't get it to work.
It was working fine yesterday, but suddenly stopped working.
Is there any outage?

Please find below the logs:

> [Thu Apr 30 2015 13:34:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port
>   12552
>   [Thu Apr 30 2015 13:34:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
>   [Thu Apr 30 2015 13:34:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING
>   /meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
>   throw(ex);
>   ^
>   [Thu Apr 30 2015 13:34:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Could not locate any
>   valid servers in initial seed list
>   at Object.Future.wait
>   (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.4.18/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
>   at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:1)
>   at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver
>   (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:1)
>   at Object. (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:1)
>   at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver
>   (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
>   at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:98:1)
>   at app/pedacity.js:4:11
>   at app/pedacity.js:100:3
>   at
>   /meteor/containers/82056e4b-b761-a84b-2709-0d43a648a6d8/bundle/programs/server/b
>   oot.js:222:10
>   at Array.forEach (native)
>
> ---
>
> at
>   /meteor/containers/82056e4b-b761-a84b-2709-0d43a648a6d8/bundle/programs/server/n
>   pm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:329:26
>   at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
>   [Thu Apr 30 2015 13:34:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
>   [Thu Apr 30 2015 13:34:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code:
>   8

Also please find the following code:

Around pedacity.js:4

```
/**
 * Collection declarations
 */
Markers = new Mongo.Collection('markers'); // This is line #4.
Segments = new Mongo.Collection('segments');
```

About pedacity.js:100, that line doesn't exist in my file... that should be the clousure automatically added by meteor.

Comment: Voting to close because, as you noted in your answer below, this problem is no longer reproducible/was caused by `a temporary outage from meteor.com hosting services.`

Answer (score 0):

All my apps deployed to *.meteor.com are also down right now with the following error:

```
WARNING Error: Could not locate any valid servers in initial seed list
```

Based on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745424/meteor-couldnt-deploy) it looks like a temporary outage that will resolve itself when the meteor folks fix it?

Comment: Fixed for me just now—IDK if it’s the same issue you were having?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a temporary outage from meteor.com hosting services.